# WPF WebHostBuilder does not contain definition for UseKestrel

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I am trying to implement single sign on using OIDC as per [GitHub](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient) but I keep getting the error:

'WebHostBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseKestrel' and no accessible extension method 'UseKestrel' accepting a first argument of type 'WebHostBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

when implementing the [SystemBrowser.cs](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient/blob/main/clients/ConsoleClientWithBrowser/SystemBrowser.cs) code

```
using IdentityModel.OidcClient.Browser;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

//other code
//simplified code extract below
IWebHost _host = new WebHostBuilder()
             .UseKestrel()
             .UseUrls(_url)
             .Configure(Configure)
             .Build();
//other code
```

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilderkestrelextensions.usekestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_WebHostBuilderKestrelExtensions_UseKestrel_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IWebHostBuilder_) it should be part of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting?

Is there something I'm missing or a NuGet package I need installing? The packages installed so far are:

[image: packages installed so far]

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you share your a screenshot about the packages in your project?Choose your project and click Dependences to choose the packages and share it to us.And What is your version of asp.net core?If it is asp.net core 3.x,the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` exists in the .net core framework by default.If does not work,maybe you need to create a new project to test it.

Comment: @Rena thanks added packages installed so far. Does UseKestrel only apply to console applications or also WPF apps?

Comment: Hi @Jack,sorry for late reply,UseKestrel also exsits in the default asp.net core web application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default asp.net core application could work well because the  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` package and other related package integrated in the framework.

I test a console application with asp.net core and reproduce your issue.Install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` together with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel`.

You could download on NuGet Package Manager by searching for the package name or download on Package Manager Console by using the command in the following reference:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel/2.2.0?_src=template